# How can I change the tab with a click response from a custom dialogue box in a tab layout

Tags: android, dialog, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, customdialog

The custom dialogue box has been called from the fragment itself and I want to move to next tab when the dialogue box return positive and stay on the same tab when dialogue box return negative.

Dialogbox code in fragment

```
  Dialog_days_selection dds = new Dialog_days_selection(getActivity());
                dds.show();
                dds.setDialogResult(new Dialog_days_selection.OnMyDialogResult() {
                    @Override
                    public void finish(int result) {
                        currentItem = result;
                        if (currentItem==2){

                            ((Subscription) getActivity()).getTabLayout().getTabAt(2).select();

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Dialog Box code for handling click events

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_ok_dialog_address:
            mDialogResult.finish(count = 2);
            dismiss();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_cancel_dialog_address:
            mDialogResult.finish(count = 1);
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
}


public void setDialogResult(OnMyDialogResult dialogResult) {
    mDialogResult = dialogResult;
}

public interface OnMyDialogResult {
    void finish(int result);
}
```

Getter method in Activiity

```
public TabLayout getTabLayout() {
    return tabLayout;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a getter method to obtain tablayout from your `Activity`

```
TabLayout getTabLayout() {
    return tabLayout;
}
```

You might have made logic in your `Fragment` to show the `AlertDialog`. Use the following piece of code in your dialog action to change the tab.

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).getTabLayout().getTabAt(INDEX_OF_THE_NEW_TAB).select();
```

Comment: Nope.. Its not working. I have added part of code. Let me know if I am handling click event correctly or not.

Comment: I found override `onclick` method and where did you assign the click listener for those buttons.

Comment: I have implemented onclicklistener in the dialog box class like this: " public class Dialog_days_selection extends Dialog implements
        android.view.View.OnClickListener"

Comment: for a button to listen to click events, you have to assign a listener to it using `button.setOnClickListener(YOUR_LISTENER)`. YOUR_LISTENER will be `this` in your case. Use break points to debug your code.

Comment: Thank You. Assigning click listener worked.. Thanks a lot.